# Why localhost path is redirecting to web URL?

Tags: php, html, redirect, localhost, htdocs

I am trying to work on a website on localhost, the folder of the project is located in htdocs. When I launch XAMPP and try to access the website in any browser (localhost:8080/project-name), it automatically redirects me to the live URL ([www.project-name.com](http://www.project-name.com)). What may be the cause of this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Maybe the website does the redirect? A guess: maybe it's a WordPress site you cloned from the live server, but you didn't yet update the `site_url` in the `wp_settings` table in your local database?

Comment: No, it is not a WP site, I coded it from scratch. There are no redirects in the code, at least I haven't found any.

Comment: Check in the browser devtools what exactly does the redirect (server? JS code? meta tag? cache?) and what the redirect response headers look like in case it's the server. This can give you some clues as to what issues the redirect and why.

Comment: OK, I check it. Thank you.

Comment: In the server case: For example, if you see an `X-Powered-By` header with PHP, or something like a `Set-Cookie` header, you know the request made its way to PHP, and you can continue looking there, for instance by adding a `die();` statement and progressively moving it further in your code until you narrowed down which part redirects you. If you don't see such a header, it's likely that Apache does the redirect, which would indicate that either the Apache config or an `.htaccess` file contain a directive that causes it.

Comment: I commented out RewriteRule ^.*$ https://project-name.com/$1 [R,L]   in .htaccess, but now I have a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Check Apache's error log for the reason.

Comment: Okay, i solved it with adding "RewriteEngine Off" to .htaccess, thank you for your help anyway.